# Wifi not working in windows10

Tags: windows-10, wifi-configuration

For about a week my wifi in windows 10 is not working ie when I click on the wifi button it does not change its colour nor it shows any signal

I tried Troubleshooting problem, checked my drivers all are ok  what is wrong with my lappy??

Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Download a LiveCD from one of the major linux distributions (I like Debian for this sort of thing.) Boot your computer from it (won't bother your Windows install) - network still no worky - hardware problem.

If that's too far out of your comfort zone, try a system restore to a time the WiFi network worked. Same diagnostic technique, just not as certain.

Check that you don't have it switched off with an airplane mode or wifi off switch, of course.

Comment: I tried system restore too

Comment: Debian is a stickler for open-source, and their basic distro excludes proprietary drivers (I ran into that with a missing Wi-Fi driver).  It may not be the best distro for this purpose unless you use the version with the non-free drivers.  Something like Mint, which is designed for out-of-the-box use by less tech savy users, is more likely to come with most common drivers, including proprietary ones.